# How to LEFT JOIN in SQL so that I can get a count of 0 to show up

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I am trying to generate a list from 2 tables (CUSTOMER & SAMPLE) that looks like this:

```
Location     Program    Sample Count   Total $$$
1              A         200            1234.56
1              B         500            7890.12
1              C         0              0
2              A         1000           9876.54
2              B         0              0
2              C         250            2345.67
```

But this is what I'm winding up with:

```
Location     Program    Sample Count   Total $$$
1              A         200            1234.56
1              B         500            7890.12
2              A         1000           9876.54
2              C         250            2345.67
```

Here's the query I'm using

```
select s.LOCATION, c.PROGRAM_CODE, count(*),
    sum(NVL(s.PRICE_AMOUNT,0) + NVL(s.RUSH_CHARGE,0) + NVL(s.ADD_TEST_PRICE,0))
from CUSTOMER c
left join SAMPLE s on c.ID = s.CUSTOMER
where 
((NVL(s.PRICE_AMOUNT,0) + NVL(s.RUSH_CHARGE,0) + NVL s.ADD_TEST_PRICE,0)) > '0.00') 
group by s.LOCATION, c.PROGRAM_CODE
order by s.LOCATION, c.PROGRAM_CODE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I see is that you are using `>` instead of `>=` in your code, so you only get items that are greater than 0. Just change `WHERE` condition to

```
where ((NVL(s.PRICE_AMOUNT,0) + NVL(s.RUSH_CHARGE,0) + NVL s.ADD_TEST_PRICE,0)) >= 0.00)
```

Keep in mind that with numbers you don't need to add `'` around the value, so instead of `'0.00'` you simply need to use `0.00`.

Answer (score 1):

Because your condition includes "**> '0.00'**"

```
where ((NVL(s.PRICE_AMOUNT,0) + NVL(s.RUSH_CHARGE,0) + NVL s.ADD_TEST_PRICE,0)) > '0.00')
```

It should be

```
where ((NVL(s.PRICE_AMOUNT,0) + NVL(s.RUSH_CHARGE,0) + NVL s.ADD_TEST_PRICE,0)) >= '0.00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. Any customer without a sample should be returned
2. If a customer has a sample but it totals 0.00 you want it excluded... from the results..

you would need an OR...

```
(((NVL(s.PRICE_AMOUNT,0) + NVL(s.RUSH_CHARGE,0) + NVL s.ADD_TEST_PRICE,0)) > '0.00')
 OR S.Customer is null)
```

However, if you simply want to return all customers then the other two answers are correct. by adjusting to '>=...' instead of '>'